# iOS 7 Store Colors in an Array

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsarray, hex, uicolor

I am making an iOS drawing app, and I want to store specific colors in a txt file and then have the file read into an array. So far I have gotten an array to read a file of hex color values, but I do not know how to use the hex values. What I want to be able to do is choose a color by referencing a certain index in the array.
For example

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, colors[2]);
```

I have not found anything that would work for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really simple, do something like this

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hexColorString alpha:(CGFloat)alpha {

    unsigned colorValue = 0;

    NSScanner *valueScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexColorString];

    if ([hexColorString rangeOfString:@"#"].location != NSNotFound) [valueScanner setScanLocation:1];

    [valueScanner scanHexInt:&colorValue];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((colorValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((colorValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:((colorValue & 0xFF) >> 0)/255.0 alpha:alpha];
}
```

**Explanation:** let's take a hex color for an example `#FFEBCD` where the # is an optional. Simply Red: FF Green: EB and Blue: CD so use right-shit operator to filter the positions and pass it to a `UIColor` factory method.

There is a nice [UIColor Extension](https://github.com/goppinath/GOExtendedUIColor) in github you can try that too. I hope which might be really useful to your App.

Comment: I implemented your code without using a method. It worked very well. Thank you.

Comment: @user3718169 thanks and please mark it as a right answer because it will be helpful for other users.